# What does the number after Unix/Linux file permissions like "-rw-rw-r--. 1 " mean in "ls -l" output

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, ls

Can any one explain `-rw-rw-r--. 1` and give some "detailed" information on ls -lart command.

Specifically, what does the number **`1`** after the file permissions mean?
 Why does it change or why is it different for different files?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions

Comment: Have you tried finding information yourself (manual pages, etc.)? Was the information unclear?

Comment: @yi_H, I don't see any information on the number after the permissions.

Comment: I was sure user1688102's question had already been asked and answered but can't find it. @Shahbaz: it;s the number of references to the same inode, i.e. the number of hard-links, i.e. the number of different names for the same file (excluding soft-links).

Comment: I've seen the man ls page. The information was not clear and no information was provided regarding permissions in man ls @Daniel

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some examples:

`-rwxrw-r-- 1` is a file with read, write and execute privileges for the owner. The group has read and write, and others have only read. There are no links to this data.

`drwxr-xr-x 10` is a directory with 8 files. The extra 2 are `.` and `..`. Only the owner can create files in this directory, others can access which files are in the directory, and read the contents of those files if the privileges allow.

`-r-------- 2` is a file which only the owner can read, but cannot execute or modify. It has a link, which means there is another file reference on disk somewhere that accesses the same data. So the actual "file content" on disk has 2 "files" referencing it. These links are often created using `ln` without supplying `-s`.

So:

- Character 1 is node type: commonly `-` or `d` indicating file or directory.
- Characters 2, 3, 4 indicate `r`ead, `w`rite, and e`x`ecute for the owner.
- Characters 5, 6, 7 do the same for the group.
- Characters 8, 9, 10 do the same for others.
- The number succeeding permission characters indicates the number of links if the node is a file, and number of "sub-nodes" if the node is a directory.

See chapter *The Long Format* of `man ls`.

Comment: As @sapht said the number(for a directory) at the end implies the number of files in a directory is wrong I guess. Because I have thousands of files in directory and it is still showing 2

Comment: I've never seen an ls that doesn't print directory subnode count using long format. Which OS/distribution are you on? Gnu ls,
, busybox and darwin all print the node count. Is it really a directory and not another node type?

Comment: My distro (Linux Mint 18.3) doesn’t have such a chapter in `ls`’s man page. None of the fields are explained there. I think it’s the same for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

**For files** it is the number of [hard-links](http://www.linfo.org/hard_link.html) to the contents of the file. 1 means no hard-links (the typical case), a number *N* above 1 means this and another *N-1* filenames share the same contents.

**For directories** [most but not all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101536/73271) filesystems report a link count of 2+*N* where *N* is the number of sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

[max@localhost ~]$ ll

total 4

drwxrwxr-x **2** max max 4096 Sep 25 17:11 zzz

Here 2 means number of link count

now I will create 3 directories inside zzz

now value changes to 5

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cd zzz
[max@localhost zzz]$ mkdir a b c
drwxrwxr-x 5 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 .
drwx------ 5 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 b
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 c
```

[max@localhost zzz]$ cd

[max@localhost ~]$ ll

total 4

drwxrwxr-x **5** max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 zzz

That is because now 5 directories are present inside zzz 3 are `a` `b` `c` and 2 are hidden directories `.` `..`

if I create file then nothing will happen to link count

```
[max@localhost zzz]$ touch 1 2 3
[max@localhost zzz]$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 5 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:26 .   ------> current directory link count
drwx------ 5 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:12 ..  ------> parent directory link count
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Sep 25 17:26 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Sep 25 17:26 2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Sep 25 17:26 3
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 b
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:16 c
[max@localhost zzz]$ cd
[max@localhost ~]$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 5 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:26 zzz
```

but if I delete any directory then link count will change

```
[max@localhost zzz]$ rmdir b c
[max@localhost zzz]$ cd
[max@localhost ~]$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 max max 4096 Sep 25 17:28 zzz
```

Comment: Much (maybe too much) detail for dirs not a word for files.